# Right design using MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

I am working in a project using MongoDB, I have a somehow large hierarchy of classes, some of them persist some others don't, I am thinking of save the name of the class as a property of the documents, for example

```
namespace foo;
class widget {
  //Properties
}
//and then the document looks like
{
_id: 56128cfba422f0d8230000b0,
//Properties 
class: 'foo\widget'
}
```

This makes easy to know what class is it mapping, is this good, common or dumb? Please any help as I am new with MongoDB and NoSql.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to store name of classes in your MongoDB. If you have classes connected with relations (like in common DB) you should save them like belove:

->Profile

-->Experience

-->Schools

---->EducationLevel

Where each of this above is connected with previous one.

Comment: Conflating classes with relations is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: I think it depends on use and application architecture. In some cases I can agree with you bot not in all.